# SignalR - Sending a Message to a subset of users

Tags: signalr

I need to send updates via SignalR to a users "Friends", not all connected users.

```
Clients.callbackName()
```

Sends a message to All Connected Clients.  How do I send a message to just a few clients?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the connection id or group name. Check out the docs for more info:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server

Answer (score 1):

To add a client to a specific group...

```
Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "johnsFriends");
```

To send a message to that clients group of friends...

```
Clients["johnsFriends"].addMessage(message);
```

Then on the client side the "addMessage" method will be invoked for all clients in the group "johnsFriends".